# Web design on Stack Overflow: Why?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am sorry if this has already been brought up before, but I'm unable to find any post of the same nature.

I wonder why Stack Overflow allows so many web design questions when web design is not really related to programming but more basic coding. I am referring to questions like [Div within Div stretching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868839/div-within-div-stretching) and [How to align images to the right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377203/how-to-align-images-to-the-right)

The FAQ State that:

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - matters that are unique to the programming profession
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

This to me personally does not cover design, web design or basic HTML. I personally think we should have a specific Stack Exchange site dedicated to the needs of designers.

> A cascading style sheet is a set of instructions that tells a web browser how to present, or display different HTML elements.

Now this (in my opinion) does not fall into the category of programming in any way.

I'm a programmer who comes to Stack Overflow every day, and ponders, answers many questions about programming and when I scroll down the list of questions and I am presented with six simple CSS questions *one after another*; it's annoying me that Stack Overflow is so ridden with questions that most of us do not want to answer.

Why is this allowed so freely and is Stack Overflow the correct place for these sorts of questions?

Comment: Related: [Which is the better site for CSS questions, Stack Overflow or Doctype?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29761). This Q&A has now been deleted, but it was a discussion about whether HTML and CSS questions are more suitable for SO or http://doctype.com, which back in the day was officially endorsed as "one of the good guys" by Stack Overflow, namely Jeff Atwood. That was eventually dropped, though (probably out of strategic considerations as SO evolved into a company) and Stack Overflow became the go-to place for HTML and CSS questions, too.

Comment: You can add `html` and `css` to your ignored tags.

Comment: I can't imagine the headache of trying to migrate the HTML/CSS questions that turn out to require scripting to solve the problem and scripting questions that turn out to only require HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 50):

Personally I don't consider myself a designer, yet I am constantly up to my elbows in HTML and CSS - IMO there is a level of implementation stuff that *is* development, not design. That can be asked and answered very well on Stack Overflow without being in the least bit out of place.

These skills are a core part of day-to-day development for a **lot** of developers...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, My point is not that web design is not important, but that it should belong in its own stack exchange apartment such as *http://doctype.com*, I would just like to see stackoverflow as the place to come to learn about real programming issues and *not* markup / styling information that is pretty simple to the average programmer.

Comment: The line is blurred at the simpler end of the questions, I'll admit...

Comment: @Robert doctype.com is not  run by SO, Inc... I think a part of the decision to keep HTML and CSS questions was simply the vast amounts of traffic they surely generate. (Not that I'm unhappy about them being here, mind...) and as @Marc says, the massive overlap with the everyday work of a web developer

Comment: As there running a platform if they created a stack site dedicated to web-design then they would only loose a small amount of traffic/revenue. I was reading on John Skeet's twitter earlier and he mentioned a 131% increase in traffic up to `17M` recently now splitting the issue into 2 sites would not loose a dramatic amount of traffic. but im not an expert on the traffic trends of SO so you may be right.

Comment: @Robert maybe there will be a separate HTML SE site one day, who knows... If people see the sense in it, I think the current arrangement works pretty okay for most. The tag is popular enough for people not to have separationist tendencies as in other fields (like DBA and testing)

Comment: @Robert see also http://ui.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Marc: So true. I'm not much of a design person either (okay, maybe a little) but I work with HTML / CSS on a daily basis.

Comment: @George, having a separate site would would not remove the support for Markup, and I think it would be beneficial on both sides of the rainbow.

Comment: @Robert: Whoa... I'm not advocating a separate site. I just agree that there is a lot of CSS involved with development even apart from design.

Comment: Exactly; there is a level of HTML/CSS that **is** fundamentally a development issue. Why move it?

Comment: a) the sites called **stack** overflow, thus referring to deeper issues regarding programming issues than regular web mark-ups and styling. b) When stackoverflow was creating is was not built specifically for the web-design market, c) just because it brings a fair amount of traffic, **we** the content creators and monitors of this community driven site have to sit back day in and day out giving help to simple issues when all our mind craves is something complex, something new, answering CSS questions for the benefit of a 1 rep user is a waste of my time imo.

Comment: It's also important to point out that Web Design is about creating logos, making images, using web design tools like Photoshop and the Gimp to produce layouts.  This generally doesn't involve HTML/CSS.  AS programmers, we never deal with those issues.  Designers, on the other hand, must also delve into HTML/CSS and can't just stay in their own little Photoshop world either.  HTML/CSS, for those in web application development, is just one of those things that exists in both worlds.

Comment: @RobertPitt: If a question seems like it isn't worth your time, don't answer. What's the issue?

Comment: @Robert - the site also hosts questions on *range* of programming topics that aren't of direct relevance to me - here's what I do: I **don't read those ones**. I'm not saying *every* developer needs to use html/css as there tool-set, but you really need to understand that those **are** fundamental development skills, directly relevant to (at a guess) 85% **or above** of our members... obviously not every question is about them, but please don't try to deny that they are part of most-every developer's job...

Comment: (next I'll have to ask my TSQL question on server fault, despite the fact that many developers do a lot more TSQL than most dbas)

Answer (score 14):

I am a new user of Stack Overflow, and I also don't want to see some questions from time to time. So I just add some tags to my **Ignored Tags** list and this works fine for me. Not ideally (ignored tags are not hidden in search results), but it works.

From my point of view, I think that web design questions in many cases may relate to programming as well. Stack Overflow contains many questions about [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) designing for example, and about other "visual" tasks. In both cases logically there is a some code, some task or bug and some kind of parser\compiler\visualizer (for example I think [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) is markup language too). So I don't know what to answer for the question "Have we an absolute necessity for a separate site or not". Maybe advanced search abilities will solve all these problems. I mean the ability to hide some undesired tags.

I also worked as a web developer and web designer and some browser behaviour drove me crazy, like most difficult bugs in my programming experience. And my actual question in those cases was deeper. It was about "Why does this algorithm in a certain browser work in that way, and not as I want".

Comment: Oops, I just found the "hide ignored tags" option in site preferences. What a surprise. Maybe StackOverflow site is already perfect :-)